# Virtual machines can only ping PFSense router and Windows Server

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox network:

PFSense with 2 adapters: NAT and a Internal Network (Lan on PFSense set to 10.0.0.1/24)
    -Windows 2016 (Internal Network)(10.0.0.2)
    -3 Windows 7 Machines(Interal network) (Static IPs .3, .4, .5) Gateway Set to the Windows 2016 machine (10.0.0.2) DNS set to the Windows 2016 Server as well

My Machines can only ping the windows 2016 box and the PFSense router, why is this?

Comment: Gateway should point to 10.0.0.1 (pfsense), not a windows PC. pFsense is your gateway to the wild internet

Comment: I've tried it both ways, same results.

Comment: In pfsense web interface go to Diagnostics->ping and try to ping external hots using WAN as source interface, can you get reply this way from external hosts like 8.8.8.8? (When you answering some1 in comments, use @ UserName such as @Alex anywhere in your comment, so user who is talking with you will be notified )

Comment: @Alex getting to the internet is fine, it's just that my windows machines cannot ping eachother

Comment: Then make sure that your PCs using private network profile(not a default public profile) in network settings

Comment: @Alex Wow, Windows Firewall will even block ICMP if it's set to public. good call Alex. Cheers

Comment: I converted our conversation to the answer so it may be help some1 else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just setup [pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/) and join new Windows PC to the network, make sure that network profile on those PCs is set to `Private`. In case of `Public` network profile, window's firewall will block any incoming connections including ICMP (ping) as well shared resources.